# how to filter using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**html**

```
    <div class="adds">
                <input type="text" value="" class="ip1" id="ip1" />
                <input type="button" value="ADD" class="btn1" id="btn1" />
                </br>
                <div class="add">
                    <ul class="justList"> 
                        <li>police</li>
                     </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="filter">
                <input type="text" value="" class="ip2" id="ip2" />
                <input type="button" value="Filter" class="btn2" id="btn2" />

                 <div class="filter">
                     <ul> 

                     </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**JS**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#btn1").on("click",function(){
        var occ = $("#ip1").val();
        if(occ.length)
         {
            $('<li />', {html: occ}).appendTo('ul.justList')
            $("#ip1").val('');
          }     
      });

     });
```

Hi Here if i give "xxxx" and click "ADD" button the text ll append in the list of ul li, i need if i click filter i need only text that equal to what i gave second input box. it should filter all "xxxx" and it must show only that. any one help me.

Comment: You must add code for filter button click also...

Comment: To be useful, a typical filter would do partial matching, not exact matching, but I have added solutions for both options below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this code works

```
$("#btn2").click(function () {
    var value = $("#ip2").val();
    $(".justList li").each(function () {
        var curr_text = $(this).text();
        if (curr_text == value) 
            console.log("equal");
        else 
            $(this).hide();
   });
});
```

Working Code:[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/Qd3n5/22/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using jQueries [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector :

```
$("#btn2").on("click", function () {
    var occ = $("#ip2").val();
    if (occ.length) {
        $matches = $('.justList li:contains("'+occ+'")');
        $matches.show();
        $('.justList li').not($matches).hide();
    }
    else{
        $('.justList li').show();
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wu2x3/1/)

**Update**

If you want a case insensitive filter, you can create custome jQuery selector by adding the following script:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
  .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

and use it in the previous script.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wu2x3/5/)

Comment: Not that I agree with it, for a filter, but the SO wanted whole text matching only.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie If you think so, then why did you include it in your answer..? btw, there's already two answers which does the both.

Comment: Hence me saying "Not that I agree with it", but because they asked of course! :) Neither existing answer used `filter`, so will not work in all cases, also they are not case insensitive. Sorry I bothered to comment. :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Well my first attempt was `filter`, but then i thought why go through all the trouble, even OP doesn't seem to be clear about the requirement. Since you bothered to comment, i updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For a filter, use jQuery [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). That is designed for this type of work.

The function passed to `filter` receives each element in turn and if you return `true` it retains it. if you return `false` it removes it.

### Partial string matching:

It also uses `match` with a *case-insensitive* RegEx (so you can specify `POL`, `pol` or `Pol` and still match `police` in your example):

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Wu2x3/2/

```
$("#btn2").on("click", function () {
    var occ = $("#ip2").val();
    var $li = $('.justList li');
    if (occ.length) {
        // Hide all, then show matches
        $li.hide();
        $li.filter(function(){
            // return true if case-insensitive match occurs
            return $(this).text().match(new RegExp(occ, "i"));
        }).show();
    }
    else{
        // Show everything
        $li.show();
    }
});
```

This converts the text values to lowercase before comparison to make the check case-insensitive.

*Note: *These solutions will also work with strings containing quotes*

### Whole string matching:

If you want to match the full string only (bit odd for a filter, but as you specified):

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Wu2x3/4/

```
$("#btn2").on("click", function () {
    var occ = $("#ip2").val();
    var $li = $('.justList li');
    if (occ.length) {
        occ = occ.toLowerCase();
        // Hide all, then show matches
        $li.hide();
        $li.filter(function(){
            // return true if case-insensitive match occurs
            return $(this).text().toLowerCase() == occ;
        }).show();
    }
    else{
        // Show everything
        $li.show();
    }
});
```